# Como pegar campos seriados com JavaFX reflecition API?

Tags: java, javafx, reflexão

Eu tenho um formulário com vários CheckBoxs, que eu nomiei c1, c2, c3, c4, c5...até  c66.  Assim:

```
@FXML
private CheckBox c1;
@FXML
private CheckBox c2;
.
.
.
@FXML
private CheckBox c66;
```

Agora eu quero fazer um org.bson.Document para colocar todos os campos com seus devidos valores. Mas para não ter que colocar um a um, gostaria de criar um 'for'. Mas não sei como envocar os CheckBox pelo nome. Algo assim:

```
 Document doc = new Document();
 for (int x = 1; x <= 66; x++) {
     CheckBox checkBox = this.getDecleredField("c" + x); //isso aqui é que eu não sei fazer
     doc.append("c" + x , checkBox.isSelected());
 }
```

Comment: Todos esses checkboxes devem estar inseridos em um Nodo pai, você pode pegar esse nodo pai, chamar o método [`getChildren()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren--) dele e a partir disto terá uma lista com todos esses checkbox (e talvez outras coisas na lista também).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opção 1:**

Adicione seus CheckBox em uma lista de CheckBox, depois navegue com um laço for dessa forma:

```
ch1 = new CheckBox("1");
ch2 = new CheckBox("2");
ch3 = new CheckBox("3");

//[...]

List<CheckBox> listaCheckBox = new ArrayList<>();
listaCheckBox.addAll(Arrays.asList(ch1,ch2,ch3, ..., ch66));

for(int i = 0; i < 66; i++){
    System.out.println("ch" + i + ":" + ch.isSelected());
}
```

**Opção 2:**

Recuperar os nós do seu painel em busca de CheckBox:

```
// É uma lista para um tipo genérico, mas se todos os filhos forem
// Checkbox pode por ObservableList<CheckBox> e retirar o if
ObservableList<Node> listaNos = seuPane.getChildren();

// Você terá que passar a quantidade exata de nós para usar um contador
// nesse laço
for(Node n: listaNos){
    if(n instanceof CheckBox){
        System.out.println(((CheckBox) n).isSelected());
    }
}
```

**Opção 3:**

Pode usar o CheckComboBox / CheckListView / CheckTreeView do [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/), são componentes muito bons para essa tarefa. Ficaria assim:

```
// Criação do CheckListView
ObservableList<String> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
lista.addAll("ch1","ch2","ch3",...,"ch66");
checklistview = new CheckListView(lista);

// Para pegar o texto de todos os selecionados é só fazer
ObservableList<String> s = adminUsuarioCbbSetor.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems();
```